# Javascript create a div,which inside have img and p from array[i]

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have this code:

```js
var imglis = ['a.jpg', 'b.jpg', 'c.jpg'] //It is the images
var imgs = "";
var descs = ["a", "b", "c"]; //It is the description
var des = "";
var price = ["200", "300", "400"]; //It is the price
var p = "";

for (var i = 0; i < imglis.length; i++) {
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  var desc = document.createElement('p');
  img.setAttribute('src', imglis[i]);
  desc.innerHTML = descs[i];
  imgs += img.outerHTML;
  des += desc.outerHTML;
}

var image = document.getElementById('image');
image.innerHTML = imgs;
var descss = document.getElementById('descss');
descss.innerHTML = des;
```

```html
<div id="image"></div>
<div id="descss"></div>
```

It works, but the result isn't what I want.
I am looking for something like :

```
   <div> // This is the div created from first array,it should have 2 more
        <div >
            <img src="a.jpg">
        </div>
        <div>
                <p>a</p>
                <p>200</price>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I stuck here for a century,please help me out.

Comment: Please fix the snippet I made you to show the issue. You can get images at https://placeholder.com/ - use appendChild to add images to a div instead of outerHTML

Comment: What is the purpose of 2 divs in your markup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your list structure so you can implement using  html concatenation with your all arrays value like this.

**DEMO**

```js
var imglis = ['a.jpg', 'b.jpg', 'c.jpg'], //It is the images
  descs = ["a", "b", "c"], //It is the description
  price = ["200", "300", "400"], //It is the price
  html = '';

for (var i = 0; i < imglis.length; i++) {
  html += `<div>
    <img src="${imglis[i]}">
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>${descs[i]}</p>
    <p>${price[i]}</p>
  </div>`;
}
document.getElementById('main-div').innerHTML = html;
```

```html
<div id="main-div"></div>
```

---

You can also use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for any one array and get your required result. This map will return an array and you can use [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to concatenation all values.

```js
const imglis = ['a.jpg', 'b.jpg', 'c.jpg'], //It is the images
  descs = ["a", "b", "c"], //It is the description
  price = ["200", "300", "400"]; //It is the price;

let html = imglis.map((v, i) => {
  return `<div><img src="${v}"></div><div><p>${descs[i]}</p><p>${price[i]}</p></div>`;
}).join('');

document.getElementById('main-div').innerHTML = html;
```

```html
<div id="main-div"></div>
```

Comment: recently, I am learning React js, is it possible to do the same with map()?btw, thank you for your answer, it works well!!

Answer (score 3):

1. use `.each()` to loop the img
2. use the index of image to get the equivalent description and price

```js
var imglis = ['a.jpg', 'b.jpg', 'c.jpg'] //It is the images

var descs = ["a", "b", "c"]; //It is the description

var price = ["200", "300", "400"]; //It is the price


$.each(imglis, function(i, v) {

  var div = $('<div></div>')
  div.append('<div><img scr=' + v + '/></div><div><p>' + descs[i] + '</p><p>' + price[i] + '</price</div>')
  $('body').append(div)





})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use This function as well to solve your problem

```js
document.onload = loadElements();

function loadElements(){
    var totalHtml = "";
    var imglis = ['a.jpg', 'b.jpg', 'c.jpg'] //It is the images
    var imgs = "";
    var descs = ["a", "b", "c"]; //It is the description
    var des = "";
    var price = ["200", "300", "400"]; //It is the price
    var p = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < imglis.length; i++) {
 var sectionDiv = document.createElement('div');

 var imageDiv = document.createElement('div');
 var contentDiv = document.createElement('div');

 var imageEle = document.createElement('img');
 var descEle = document.createElement('p');
 var priceEle = document.createElement('p');

 imageEle.setAttribute('src', imglis[i]);
 descEle.innerHTML = descs[i];
 priceEle.innerHTML = price[i];

 imageDiv.innerHTML = imageEle.outerHTML;
 contentDiv.innerHTML = descEle.outerHTML + priceEle.outerHTML;

 sectionDiv.innerHTML = imageDiv.outerHTML + contentDiv.outerHTML;
 totalHtml += sectionDiv.outerHTML;
    }

    var elem = document.getElementById('contentHtml');
    elem.innerHTML = totalHtml;
}
```

```html
<div id="contentHtml"></div>
```